# Precision (digits) of ERC-1155 tokens

Tags: erc-1155

Where can you define the number of decimals of NFTs when using the ERC1155 standard?

Comment: The current and correct way to do it is in the metadata of the NFT itself.
You just need to add a root item called decimals.
Here is an example:
https://assets.skyweaver.net/latest/metadata/1.json

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same way they are determined in ERC20:

- You pass them in [the constructor](https://gist.github.com/coinfork/27f6ea49366bf3834b37d202a34a0422#file-erc20tokenfaucet-abi-L148)
- You get them via [function decimals](https://gist.github.com/coinfork/27f6ea49366bf3834b37d202a34a0422#file-erc20tokenfaucet-abi-L201)

And all it took for me to find this out was:

1. Search `ERC-1155` on Google
2. Click on [the first result](https://blog.enjincoin.io/erc-1155-the-crypto-item-standard-ac9cf1c5a226)
3. Scroll down to `The Standard` section
4. Click on the `TENJ Token: 0x33fcaef31a637c96207e99b1a1189e1eb4640976 ABI` bullet
5. Search the word `decimals` via Ctrl/F

Comment: H, why thge word "decimals" is missing in https://github.com/enjin/erc-1155/blob/master/contracts/IERC1155.sol and in https://github.com/enjin/erc-1155/blob/master/contracts/ERC1155.sol ? Is it an error?

Comment: @porton: I don't know, but these guys didn't even bother to verify this token contract on Etherscan, so I wouldn't take their work too seriously (also, as obvious from the fact which you've just noticed, they've posted this standard but didn't bother to implement it in full).

Comment: BTW, `decimals` does appear if you scroll down in their [GitHub project's main webpage](https://github.com/enjin/erc-1155#erc-1155-reference-implementation) and open the `EIP-1155 issue thread` link.